# Consumer Driven Contracts with SOAP web services

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, pact, spring-cloud-contract

Does any of you know any approach or tools to implement Consumer Driven Contracts with SOAP web services? I have a legacy Java application that publishes SOAP web services, implemented with Apache CXF, which are consumed by a bunch of Spring Boot Java microservices. I’m already using Pact and Spring Cloud Contract to test my REST calls between the microservices, but could not find a way to use these same tools, or any other, for SOAP web services.

Answer (score 1):

There is [JavaSeifenBenutzer](https://github.com/koflTW/JavaSeifenBenutzer)

> a project to create Soap/Xml support for pact-jvm via a reverse proxy that converts XML to JSON and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Cloud Contract with MockMvc and RestDocs to build stubs of the XML service. Then you have to package the stubs in a jar for other people to reuse it and that's it.